# How do you avoid the "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm currently working on a maze generating algorithm called recursive division. The algorithm is quite simple to understand: Step 1: if the height of your chamber is smaller than the width, divide your grid/chamber with a vertical line. If the height is greater than the width, then divide your chamber with a horizontal line. Step 2: Repeat step 1 with the sub-chambers that were created by the lines. You want to repeat these steps until you get a maze (until the width or height equals 1 unit).

The problem that I have with this algorithm is that JavaScript prints out a RangeError, meaning that I called the function that creates the maze too many times (I'm trying to implement this algorithm with a recursive function). Is there any way to avoid/prevent this from happening? Or am I missing something important in my code that makes the algorithm not work properly?

I have tried to implement a trampoline function, but since I'm a beginner I just don't understand it well enough to implement my self. I have also restarted my entire project ruffly 3 times with some hope that I will come up with a different approach to this problem, but I get the same error every time.

**My code here:**

```
//leftCord = the left most x coordinate of my chamber/grid, upCord = the upmost y coordinate of my 
grid etc.

//(0, 0) IS POSITIONED IN THE LEFT TOP NODE OF MY GRID

function createMaze(leftCord, rightCord, upCord, downCord) {
var height = Math.abs(downCord - upCord);
var width = Math.abs(rightCord - leftCord);

if (height < 2 || width < 2) {
    //The maze is completed!
    return;
} else {

    if (height < width) {
        //cut the chamber/grid vertically

        //Getting a random number that's EVEN and drawing the function x = 'random number' on the grid
        var x = randomNum(leftCord / 2, rightCord / 2) * 2;

        var lineX = [];
        for (i = upCord; i < downCord; i++) {
            lineX.push(grid[i][x]);
        }

        //Making a random door/passage and making sure it's ODD
        var randomDoor = randomNum(0, lineX.length / 2) * 2 + 1;
        lineX.splice(randomDoor, 1);

        //Drawing the line
        for (i = 0; i < lineX.length; i++) {
            lineX[i].className = "wall";
        }

        //Making the same thing again, but with the left and right sub-chambers that were created by the line
        createMaze(leftCord, x, upCord, downCord);
        createMaze(x, rightCord, upCord, downCord);

    } else {
        //cut the chamber/grid horizontally

        //Getting a random number that's EVEN and drawing the function y = 'random number' on the grid
        var y = randomNum(0, downCord / 2) * 2;

        var lineY = [];
        for (i = leftCord; i < rightCord; i++) {
            lineY.push(grid[y][i]);
        }

        //Making a random door/passage and making sure it's ODD
        var randomDoor = randomNum(0, lineY.length / 2) * 2 + 1;
        lineY.splice(randomDoor, 1);

        //Drawing the line
        for(i = 0; i < lineY.length; i++){
            lineY[i].className = "wall";
        }

        //Making the same thing again, but with the upper and lower-chambers that were created by the line
        createMaze(leftCord, rightCord, upCord, y);
        createMaze(leftCord, rightCord, y, downCord);
    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you never initialize `i` with `var`- it is sent into the global scope and is overwritten each function call.

Comment: I just updated my code and the problem still remains. I already initialized "i" with "var" earlier in my code, so that means that I simply reset the value of "i" every time I use a for loop

Comment: You better define a new var for the counter of each for loop. Instead of using `for (i = 0; i < lineX.length; i++) {` just use `for (var i = 0; i < lineX.length; i++) {`.This will eliminate sideffects due to `i` is scoped to the loop and will not be left with the value of `lineX.length` once for loop has been finished. If you do not use the `var` part and already have `i` defined somewhere before, this will result in the prior defined `i` having the value `lineX.length` too which then might lead to unwanted results.